# Extending grouping code to handle more general inputs

Tags: python, list

I need to group either a list of floats, or a list of (named)tuples of varying length, into groups based on whether or not the key is bigger or smaller than a given value.

For example given a list of powers of 2 less than 1, and a list of cutoffs:

```
twos = [2**(-(i+1)) for i in range(0,10)]
cutoffs = [0.5, 0.125, 0.03125]
```

Then function

```
split_into_groups(twos, cutoffs)
```

should return

```
[[0.5], [0.25, 0.125], [0.0625, 0.03125], [0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
```

I've implemented the function like this:

```
def split_by_prob(items, cutoff, groups, key=None):
    for k,g in groupby(enumerate(items), lambda (j,x): x<cutoff):
        groups.append((map(itemgetter(1),g)))
    return groups

def split_into_groups(items, cutoffs, key=None):
    groups = items
    final = []
    for i in cutoffs:
        groups = split_by_prob(groups,i,[],key)
        if len(groups) > 1:
            final.append(groups[0])
            groups = groups.pop()
        else:
            final.append(groups[0])
            return final
    final.append(groups)
    return final
```

The tests that these currently pass are:

```
>>> split_by_prob(twos, 0.5, [])
[[0.5], [0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]

>>> split_into_groups(twos, cutoffs)
[[0.5], [0.25, 0.125], [0.0625, 0.03125], [0.015625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125, 0.0009765625]]
>>> split_into_groups(twos, cutoffs_p10)
[[0.5, 0.25, 0.125], [0.0625, 0.03125, 0.015625], [0.0078125, 0.00390625, 0.001953125], [0.0009765625]]
```

Where `cutoffs_p10 = [10**(-(i+1)) for i in range(0,5)]`

I can straightforwardly extend this to a list of tuples of the form

```
items = zip(range(0,10), twos)
```

by changing

```
def split_by_prob(items, cutoff, groups, key=None):
    for k,g in groupby(enumerate(items), lambda (j,x): x<cutoff):
        groups.append((map(itemgetter(1),g)))
    return groups
```

to

```
def split_by_prob(items, cutoff, groups, key=None):
    for k,g in groupby(enumerate(items), lambda (j,x): x[1]<cutoff):
        groups.append((map(itemgetter(1),g)))
    return groups
```

How do I go about extending the original method by adding a key that defaults to a list of floats (or ints etc) but one that could handle tuples and namedtuples?

For example something like:

```
split_into_groups(items, cutoffs, key=items[0])
```

would return

```
[[(0,0.5)], [(1,0.25), (2,0.125)], [(3,0.0625), (4,0.03125)], [(5,0.015625), (6,0.0078125), (7,0.00390625), (8,0.001953125), (9,0.0009765625)]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer I assume, the cutoffs are at the end in increasing order - just to simplify the situation.

## `Discriminator` detecting a slot

```
class Discriminator(object):
    def __init__(self, cutoffs):
        self.cutoffs = sorted(cutoffs)
        self.maxslot = len(cutoffs)
    def findslot(self, num):
        cutoffs = self.cutoffs
        for slot, edge in enumerate(self.cutoffs):
            if num < edge:
                return slot
        return self.maxslot
```

## `grouper` to put items into slots

```
from collections import defaultdict
def grouper(cutoffs, items, key=None):
    if not key:
        key = lambda itm: itm
    discr = Discriminator(cutoffs)
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for item in items:
        num = key(item)
        result[discr.findslot(num)].append(item)
    return result

def split_into_groups(cutoffs, numbers, key=None):
    groups = grouper(cutoffs, numbers, key)
    slot_ids = sorted(groups.keys())
    return [groups[slot_id] for slot_id in slot_ids]
```

## Conclusions about Discriminator and `grouper`

Proposed Discriminator works even for unsorted items.

## Conclusions about `key`

In fact, providing the `key` functions is easier, than it originally looked.

It is just a function provided via parameter, so it becomes an alias for the transformation function to call to get the value, we want to use for comparing, grouping etc.

There is special case of `None`, for such a situation we have to use some identity function.

Simplest one is

```
func = lambda itm: itm
```

Note: all the functions above were tested by a test suite (incl. use of `key` function, but I removed it from this answer as it was becoming far too long.

Comment: @TomKealy Finally I included the `key` answer to your `key` question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you possibly explain why you took the route you did, and perhaps why the code I wrote couldn't be extended to do what I needed?

Comment: @TomKealy I did it this way for poor reasons like: I like it my way, I did not read properly what you really asked for (the `key` part) first and started with rewrite. For practical reasons, it allowed me to clearly split the concept of finding the slot, and the concept of finding an element in grouped data to use for deciding the slot to use. Anyway, your code look of good quality, I like it, but I was too lazy to dive into all the details.